# Reducing complexity from permutation to combination

Tags: c#, algorithm

Lets say I have 6 image parts that forms a single image when correctly arranged. Also suppose that I have 2 pair of parts that may be interchanged in position and may still form the same image. Now, I want all the possible combinations without permutation. I want to start from 1st place and check how many partials fits that place and incrementally move towards last place.

```
List<List<int>> possible_combinations = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
           foreach (var comb in possible_combinations)
              {
                 List<int[]> best_combination = new List<int[]>();
                 for (int p = 0; p < comb.Count; p++)
                      best_combination.AddRange(allStrokes[comb[p]]);
                 if (!comb.Contains(i))
                 {
                     best_combination.AddRange(allStrokes[i]);
                     var fits = cs.checkFeasibility(best_combination);
                     if (fits)
                        comb.Add(i);
                 }
             }
         }
```

possible combination already may consists of all first possible partial image id. Check feasibility will check if newly combined partial will improve the result so far or not. How can I achieve that. Code herewith is for reference for understanding.

Comment: I think what you described is permutation with extended steps. Since order of the things matter, it will end up as a permutation.

Comment: @Emut I think that unlike permutation, 6x5x4x3x2x1 combination, I want 6+5+4+3+2+1 since the first element is locked when it is a match and complexity reduces